# fusionchart addEventListener not working

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using fusionchart and I wasn't able to use the `addEventListener` function. It's throwing me JavaScript error.  In this JavaScript file the chart is loading and working fine if I remove the `addEventListener` function..

I have downloaded another fusioncharts_latestdownload.js file from the site.  The `addEventListener` function is working in this new file but the chart is not getting loaded
Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but my crystal ball isn't working tonight. Guess I'll have to get it tuned up _again_

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code here so that it can be tested?

Comment: @Sanjukta : please check this link..i have attached the js files in that forum..http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/9848-in-fusionchartjs-could-not-able-to-use-addeventlistener/#entry38462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionCharts allows you to set event listeners in charts (swf/js) built since v3.2. So, please check if you are using charts having version 3.2 or above.

Moreover, please also check if you have FusionCharts.js which is of v3.2 or above.

More pointers on adding event listeners:

1. Make sure to use the appropriate variable name/js reference of the chart.

   `var myChart = new FusionCharts(...);`
   `myChart.addEventListener ("DrawComplete" , myChartListener );`

Basic Documentation : http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?JavaScript/JS_EventOverview.html#advanced

API Reference : http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/?JavaScript/API/Events.html

1. You can also use other chart reference models like:

   `FusionCharts("myChartId").addEventListener("DrawComplete" , myChartListener);`
   `getChartFromId( DOMId ).addEventListener("DrawComplete" , myChartListener);`
   `FusionCharts.items["myChartId"].addEventListener("DrawComplete" , myChartListener);`

You can also check out samples from :

http://www.fusioncharts.com/code/JavaScript/Basics/ListeningToEvents/Using_JavaScript_advanced_event_registration_model.html

Menu containing other examples of FusionCharts JavaScript API : http://www.fusioncharts.com/code/JavaScript/index.html